Updating API to remove a time option once it has been selected on a given date
Working on writing a booking application. I want the time options to update based on information kept in the local storage. A selected time option for a given date should be removed from the availability array for that day once the form gets submitted.
Below is the child Form Component:
import { Button } from '../../components/Button'
import silhouetteLogo from '../../images/silouhette_logo-removebg-preview.png'
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { DateComponent } from '../../components/Date';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

export function BookingForm({ formSubmission }) {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
            time: 'Select Time',
            firstName: '',
            email: '',
            confirmButton: false,
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
            date: Yup.date()
                .test(
                    'date',
                    'The date you selected has already passed.',
                    function (date) { return new Date(date) >= new Date(); }
                )
                .required('Required'),
            time: Yup.string()
                .notOneOf(['Select Time'], 'Please select one of our available time slots.')
                .required('Please select one of our available time slots.'),
            firstName: Yup.string().required('Required').trim(),
            email: Yup.string().email('Please enter a valid email address').required('Required').trim(),
            confirmButton: Yup.boolean().oneOf([true], 'You must confirm the information above is accurate to submit your booking'),
        }),
        onSubmit:
            (values) => {
                formSubmission(values);
                
}
});

    const availability = window.fetchAPI(formik.values.date);
    return (
        <form data-testid='booking-form' onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <fieldset className='scheduleCheck'>
                <h1 className="scheduleCheckTitle">Tell us about your Party!</h1>
                <div id='scheduleChecker' className='scheduleCheckInputs'>
                    <div className="date">
                        <label htmlFor='date'>Date</label>
                        <input id='date' type='text' className='form-control visually-hidden' value={formik.values.date} onChange={formik.handleChange} onBlur={formik.handleBlur} />
                        <DateComponent
                            id='visible-date'
                            selected={formik.values.date}
                            className={formik.touched.date && formik.errors.date ? "form-control error date" : "form-control"}
                            onChange={(d) => formik.setFieldValue('date', d)}
                            onChangeRaw={(e) => formik.setFieldTouched('date', e.target.value)}
                            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                            ariaHidden
                            required
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="dropdown time">
                        <label htmlFor='time'>Time</label>
                        <select
                            id='time'
                            name='time'
                            type="button"
                            className={formik.touched.time && formik.errors.time ? 'btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle error' : "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"}
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            value={formik.values.time}
                            onChange={formik.handleChange}
                            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                            required
                        >
                            <option value='Select Time'>Select Time</option>
                            {availability.map((time, index) => <option data-testid='time-option' className="dropdown-item" value={time} key={index}>{time}</option>)}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div >
                <div>
                    {formik.touched.date && formik.errors.date ? <div data-testid='validation-field' className='schedule-check-error'>{formik.errors.date}</div> : null}
                    {formik.touched.time && formik.errors.time ? <div data-testid='validation-field' className='schedule-check-error'>{formik.errors.time}</div> : null}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div className='infoInput'>
                <fieldset className='infoInput'>
                    <div className='bookingTitle'>
                        <h1>Complete Your Booking!</h1>
                        <img className='silhouetteLogo' src={silhouetteLogo} alt='little lemon logo' />
                    </div>
                    <div className='contactInfo'>
                        <div className="row name">
                            <div className="col firstName">
                                <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                                <input
                                    id='firstName'
                                    name='firstName'
                                    type="text"
                                    className={formik.touched.firstName && formik.errors.firstName ? "form-control error" : "form-control name-input"}
                                    value={formik.values.firstName}
                                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                    placeholder=' '
                                    required
                                />
                                {formik.touched.firstName && formik.errors.firstName ? <div data-testid='validation-field' className='error-message'>{formik.errors.firstName}</div> : null}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row phemail">
                            <div className="col email">
                                <label htmlFor="email" >Email Address</label>
                                <input
                                    id='email'
                                    name='email'
                                    type="email"
                                    className={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email ? "form-control error" : "form-control email"}
                                    value={formik.values.email}
                                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                    required
                                />
                                {formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email ? <div data-testid='validation-field' className='error-message'>{formik.errors.email}</div> : null}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className="align-items-center completeForm">
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className="col form-check mb-2 confirm">
                            <input
                                className={formik.touched.confirmButton && formik.errors.confirmButton ? 'error form-check-input' : 'form-check-input'}
                                type="checkbox"
                                id="confirmButton"
                                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                                checked={formik.values.confirmButton}
                                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                                required />
                            <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="confirmButton">
                                Check here to confirm the above information is accurate
                            </label>
                            {formik.touched.confirmButton && formik.errors.confirmButton ? <div data-testid='validation-field' className='error-message'>{formik.errors.confirmButton}</div> : null}
                        </div>
                        <div className="col bookButton">
                            <Button testId='submit' type='submit' onClick={formik.handleSubmit} textVariant=' Book My Table' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form >
    )
}

Next is the parent component that contains the page layout and formSubmission function. You'll noticed I am intentionally only saving the date and the time to the local storage:
import { BookingForm } from "./BookingForm"
import { ConfirmedBooking } from "./ConfirmedBooking"
import restaurant from "../../images/restaurant-image.jpg"
import './Booking.css';
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Hero } from "../Home/Hero";

export function Booking() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const formSubmission = (values) => {
        console.log('Form submitted:', values);
        if (window.submitAPI(values)) {
            alert('Your reservation has been submitted!');
            localStorage.setItem('date', values.date);
            localStorage.setItem('time', values.time);
            navigate('/ConfirmedBooking');
        } else {
            alert('There was an error with your submission. Please try again.');
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Hero
                title='Reservations'
                text="Come enjoy a meal with us in our restaurant space. With our gorgeous Mediterranean decor, you will feel like you have been transported to Greece! Can’t make it in for your event? We also offer catering services!We are a family-owned Mediterranean restaurant, focused on traditional recipes served with a modern twist"
                image={restaurant}
                alt='restaurant-image'
                textVariant='Catering Menu'
                path='/Menu'
            />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/BookingForm" element={<BookingForm formSubmission={formSubmission} />} />
                <Route path="/ConfirmedBooking" element={<ConfirmedBooking />} />
            </Routes>
            <BookingForm formSubmission={formSubmission} />
        </>
    )
}

and lastly the code for the api that is being called:
const seededRandom = function (seed) {
    var m = 2 ** 35 - 31;
    var a = 185852;
    var s = seed % m;
    return function () {
        return (s = s * a % m) / m;
    };
}

var fetchAPI = function (date) {
    if (!(date instanceof Date)) {
        date = new Date(date);
    };

    let result = [];
    let random = seededRandom(date.getDate());

    for (let i = 5; i <= 11; i++) {
        if (random() < 0.5) {
            result.push(i + ':00 PM');
        }
        if (random() < 0.5) {
            result.push(i + ':30 PM');
        }
    }
    return result;
};
var submitAPI = function (formData) {
    return true;
};

I have watched a number of videos on how to work with local storage, and have a fairly good grasp on how that works, but am struggling with being able to apply the date and time data saved in local storage to update the desired components.
What make this situation a little more complex is that I am not currently using the useState hook. Instead my state is being handled by useFormik since I needed assistance with my form validation too. The formSubmission function is supposed to stay in the parent component, but I can't seem to both nicely maintain the state for the form, and use it to filter out the time array for a given date with each submission.
Any assistance is appreciated.

I ended up making adjustments to the fetchAPI function in the api.js file with the following code:
export function fetchAPI(selectedDate) {

    if (!(selectedDate instanceof Date)) {
        selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
    };
var submissionData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Date and Time'));
    let bookedTimes = submissionData ? submissionData
        .filter((data) => new Date(data.date).toDateString() === selectedDate.toDateString())
        .map((data) => data.time) : [];

    let result = [];

    let random = seededRandom(selectedDate);

    for (let i = 5; i <= 11; i++) {
        var proposed1 = i + ':00 PM';
        var proposed2 = i + ':30 PM';
        if (random() < 0.5 && !bookedTimes.includes(proposed1)) {
            result.push(proposed1);
        }
        if (random() < 0.5 && !bookedTimes.includes(proposed2)) {
            result.push(proposed2);
        }
    }
    return result;

The conditional statements first check whether or not the selected date appears in the local storage at all, and then proceeds to map through the returned results from the filter to create the bookedTimes variable. If the iterations result in no matches, the value of bookedTimes is an empty array.
Lastly the bookedTimes array is used to conditionally assess and complete the for loop only pushing the values of proposed 1 and 2 to result if they do not already appear in bookedTimes. The result array assigned to the availability in the BookingForm thus actively updating the available times based on the local storage.
Yes I am aware that this example only works on a single device and would need to be adapted in a real time situation. Additionally, any time the local storage is reset, so would the time options.
